# Setup two ingress for two services with same names in different namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have 2 namespaces called `dev` and `stage`
in both namespaces I have similar setups. In both namespaces I have service called frontend.

I wanted to set up an ingress for this. I set up ingress in both namespaces with the following config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev.myapp.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
```

In the stage just changed the host to `stage.myapp.io`. It is not working for one of the namespaces. 
Does my approach is correct? Or I need to set up ingress in another namepace (Kube-system maybe) and point paths in the same ingress?

PS: If I change service names and keep it different, 2 ingress works just fine but I want to set up services with same namespace, as it simplifies my other deployments.

Comment: so, when you change only the service name (say from frontend to frontend1), it starts working?

Comment: A description of "it is not working" isn't helpful. Is it 404-ing? times out? eats your lunch? What's in the ingress controller logs for those requests that you would expect to work?

Comment: @suren yes if I change my service names it just works.

Comment: Are you specifying the namespace name while deploying this yaml?

Comment: Ingress rules need to be in the same namespace of the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are supposed to include the namespace annotation to your Ingress. Considering it, your yaml files should look like this:

Dev:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-dev
  namespace: dev
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev.myapp.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
```

Stage:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-stage
  namespace: stage
spec:
  rules:
  - host: stage.myapp.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
```